# str_replace php replacing text with a parameter

Tags: php, loops, str-replace

I have this function which someone here helped me minimize to be more efficient but the problem is that this more efficient code isn't working the way I had it originally.

**New Class Function**

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
foreach($d as $item=>$value){
  $txt = str_replace('{'.$value.'}',$item[$value],$fn);
  //as well as
  // $txt = str_replace('{$value}',$item[$value],$fn);
  echo $txt;
  }
}
```

**Original Class Function**

```
public function iterate($d,$t,$fn){
   foreach($d as $item){
   if($t == "post"){
    $txt = str_replace('{author}',$item["author"],$fn);
    $txt = str_replace('{id}',$item["id"],$txt );
$txt = str_replace('{content}',$item["content"],$txt);
    $txt = str_replace('{date}',$item["date"],$txt);
    echo $txt;
    }
   }
}
```

to Instantiate the function I do

```
easyCMS->iterate($post,'<div class="post" id="post_{id}">{content}</div><div class="author">{author} on {date}</div>');
```

The new function outputs this:

```
<div class="post" id="post_{id}">{content}</div>
<div class="author">{author} on {date}</div>
```

My original function outputs correctly for example.

```
<div class="post" id="post_1">Hello World</div>
<div class="author">Mr.EasyBB on 5/28/2014</div>
```

Am I missing something why would my original work perfectly and not this new smaller more "efficient" code not do the trick?

**UPDATE**

var_dump($value);

```
  array(12) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
    [1]=> string(59) "Hello this is post one testing iterator easyCMS->iterate();" ["content"]=> string(59) "Hello this is post one testing iterator easyCMS->iterate();" 
    [2]=> string(9) "Mr.EasyBB" ["author"]=> string(9) "Mr.EasyBB" 
    [3]=> string(10) "2014-05-24" ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-05-24" 
    [4]=> string(11) "Recent Post" ["category"]=> string(11) "Recent Post" 
    [5]=> string(26) "html,css,javascript,jquery" ["tags"]=> string(26) "html,css,javascript,jquery" 
   }
```

Comment: Change `$item[$value]` to this `$value[$item]` in your new class function.

Comment: still same output see http://minjs.site88.net/

Comment: must iterate `$value` `$txt = $fn; foreach ($value as $k => $v){$txt = str_replace('{'.$k.'}', $v, $txt);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the replacement wrong in the function:

```
public function iterate($d,$fn){
                           ^^^---original string
foreach($d as $item=>$value){
  $txt = str_replace('{'.$value.'}',$item[$value],$fn);
                                                  ^^^---always use the original string
```

It should be

```
foreach(...) {
    $fn = str_replace(....., $fn);
    ^^^^---change this
}
echo $fn;
```

so that you're constantly modifying the string that was modified in the previous iteration.

Right now you're doing

```
$original (change {foo}) -> $modified
$original (change {bar}) -> $modified
```

instead of

```
$original (change{foo}) -> $modified
$modified (change{bar}) -> $modified_again
$modified_again (etc....
```

Comment: Ok I see what you've done, except that it still did the same thing.

Comment: @RahilWazir done both and it still outputs the same. It's odd I can see what Marc B is saying and it's perfectly true, because I had to change my original functions replacee

Comment: you also have to move the `echo`. You're doing it INSIDE the loop, so you'd be constantly dumping out the partially changed string, instead of just the final product after the replacements are done.

Comment: See that's what I thought I just never tried it because I didn't want some funky output worse than it already is. I will try that as well Marc--edit-- Moving echo outside of the loop echos only one post the original will echo all post.

Answer (score 0):

Marc B is right. Here's what I think you need:

```
public function iterate($d, $fn) {
    foreach ($d as $item => $value) {
        $fn = str_replace('{' . $item . '}', $value, $fn);
    }
    echo $fn;
}
```

Good luck!